# How to update a Podio category using PHP API

Tags: podio

I'm using a webhook to kick off a series of PHP scripts that take advantage of the Podio PHP API.  I've tried using several different API calls but haven't been able to sort this out.  This is a test file I'm using so the actual logic of what its doing doesn't make much sense.  When I run the code below I get the error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PodioBadRequestError: "Invalid value "status" (string): Not a valid option"
Request URL: http://api.podio.com/item/<removed>/value/<removed>

Stack Trace:
/data/www/default/contracts/lib/podio-php-master/lib/Podio.php(357): 
Podio::request('PUT', '/item/<removed>...', Array)
/data/www/default/contracts/lib/podio-php-master/models/PodioItemField.php(55): Podio::put('/item/<removed>...', Array)
/data/www/default/contracts/test-category.php(25): 
PodioItemField::update(<removed>, <removed>, Array, Array)
{main}
  thrown in /data/www/default/contracts/lib/podio-php-master/lib/Podio.php on line 291`
```

Here is my code:

```
//dummy item_id
$item_id = 123456789;

//dummy field_id      
$field_id = 987654321;

//Get the category field value
$item = PodioItem::get_field_value($item_id, $field_id);

//Create a variable with the text of the selected category option for validation
$button_value = $item[0]['value']['text'];

//Print the text of the selected option
print $button_value;

//Now that I have validated the current selection I want to change it 
//These are the names of the attributes for my category
$my_attributes = array("status", "text", "id", "color");

//These are the values I want to update them to
$my_options = array("active","Generated",21,"DCEBD8");

//This should update the record in podio with the new values
PodioItemField::update($item_id, $field_id, $my_attributes, $my_options);
```

I reviewed all of the examples in the documentation but I feel like I'm missing something simple.  Is anyone familiar with this that can tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I've tried to comment the code to make it clear what I expect to be happing on each line but I can definitely clarify more if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the attributes in the wrong method. To update the Category field you just pass the `id` of the option that you want to change in an array. So the `$my_attributes` array must be like,

```
$my_attributes = array(21);//id of the category option
```

And the `$my_options` array should like this,

```
 $my_options = array('silent' => true, 'hook' => false);
```

This should update the item in Podio with the new values,

```
PodioItemField::update($item_id, $field_id, $my_attributes, $my_options);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you for the explanation.